# GCD and foreign thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a way I can create a new (or associate an existing) dispatch queue and tie it to a specific thread?

I have an AudioUnit callback proc running on a thread I do not control and would like, prior to executing the callback proper, check if some given queue has any block for me to process within that AudioUnit thread.

I can probably use OSAmtomicEnqueue and friends, but was wondering whether GCD already offered some kind of "escape" allowing me to tie a specific thread to a specific queue?

Comment: The only related answer I could find: http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Sep/msg00172.html ... doesn't bode too well. Might have to roll my own fifo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple'doc, the answer is no.

> GCD provides and manages FIFO queues to which your application can
>   submit tasks in the form of block objects. Blocks submitted to
>   dispatch queues are executed on a pool of threads fully managed by the
>   system. No guarantee is made as to the thread on which a task
>   executes.

Comment: Too bad ... atomic stuff it will be then :-(