# recycleURLs:completionHandler: with NIL makes it block until completion?

Tags: objective-c

I was sending a file to the trash with

```
[NSWorkSpace recycleURLs: myArrayOfOneNsurl
             completionHandler: NIL]
```

`myArrayOfOneNsurl` is a `NSArray` created with `arrayWithObject:` of a single `NSURL` that was created for an absolute file path with `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`.

The normal way to tell if it is successful is to use the `completionHandler` and then check if the 2nd arg (`NSError`) is `NIL`, which means success.

Is there anyway to check success without this callback? Currently I have setup a loop after calling this, to check for file existence, if 1second has past and it still exists, I declare fail. I was wondering if I set `NIL` as second arg to `recycleURLs:completionHandler:` does it make it block until the process completes (regardless of success)? In my tests, the very first check always finds that the file is no longer at its original place (meaning it was trashed), but I'm not sure if my computer is just super fast, or it really is blocking until file operation completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For trashing a single file or directory, you can use `NSFileManager trashItemAtURL` instead. It is synchronous, so you avoid the headaches with the completion callback.

```
NSError * error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] trashItemAtURL:url resultingItemURL:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Shoot this turned out to only be 10.8+ and I needed to support 10.6+ :( I had to go with the async thing below and do a sleep and check till was gone :(

Answer (score 1):

This API is async. Passing `NULL` as `completionHandler` only means, that you are not interested in result. The only way to know when operation finished and was it successful is using `completionHandler`.

If you really need to make it sync, you may use following approach (although I don't recommend that):

```
__block BOOL recycleFinished = NO;
__block NSError *recycleError = nil;
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] recycleURLs:myArrayOfOneNsurl
                         completionHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSURL *,NSURL *> * _Nonnull newURLs, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    recycleFinished = YES;
    recycleError = error;
}];

while (!recycleFinished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.5]];
}

// access recycleError
NSLog(@"%@", recycleError);
```

Comment: Aw shoot. Thanks very much for the sync work around. My problem is I am doing this via FFI calls, and there is a bug in the platform I am deving for, in that I can only setup callbacks on the mainthread. My code runs in thread, so if I use any callback that dispatches to the mainthread, then my platform crashes. :( Is there any alternative to `recyleURLs` that is sync and runnable from thread? It seems ` performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation ` was deprecated in 10.11 :(

Comment: Using `recycleURLs: completionHandler:`, you will receive `completionHandler` on the same dispatch queue. Or, you can still use `performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation`, although it's deprecated. For now, it still available, but this may change in future releases. Unfortunately, I see no other options, but I'm not very familiar with this API.

Comment: Thanks for that info @Boris! :) This is an XY question but, is there a way to setup the thread to be the dispatch queue? (aside from the obvious, the caller was the thread, i guess caller is dispatcher) Do I have to run a loop or something?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, looks like the answer is "no". See following question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393209/gcd-and-foreign-thread . Otherwise, I suggest to ask new question ;)